# Wired Connection not workin in XUBUNTU 18.04LTS

Tags: xubuntu, ethernet

HI I have download XUbuntu 18.04 LTS and a I am new to it.
I want to connect my laptop with wired connections (Ethernet), but its only connect to WiFi. Is there anyway to connect. First i read some comment but nothing of them helped me. I open terminal and I wrote `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and the output was:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

after I add :

```
#primary interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and save it and then i write in terminal: `sudo service network manager restart` .

But the problem is the same , when I open the network in the higher right  it only connected with WiFi and it says internet network disconnected . I disable the WiFi ,enable network again the same problem only with WiFi. I opened terminal and write:

`$ ifconfig` , it doesnt have `eth0` or 1 only enp3s0 . 
The output is excactly :

```
enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 48:5b:39:0b:25:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2538  bytes 234312 (234.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2538  bytes 234312 (234.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::eff2:54f7:eab9:388e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1c:4b:d6:7a:d5:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 43031  bytes 50134095 (50.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26768  bytes 3721787 (3.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Does any one has an idea how to fix , i have read a lot by the comment of 2013, 2010 and 2017 and i don't know what to do??.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding enp3s0 to your interface-config, because it seems to be the eth0 you are missing:

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

(enp3sX is just a different naming-scheme based on biosdevname)

Addendum: [DELLs specifications about "consistent network device naming in linux"](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/consistent_network_device_naming_in_linux.pdf)

Addendum 2: [Since bionic beaver, netplan is used for network interface configuration](https://netplan.io/)

Comment: HI Juergen. I change to # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#primary interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp          and after I MADE A restart network manager but nothing happend with lan

Comment: "and save it and then i write in terminal: sudo service network manager restart"

i hope you did
"sudo service network-manager restart"
instead.

try installing and utilizing "lshw" for exploring your local situation further, look for

  *-network:* *
       logical name: {ADAPTERNAME}